# "general/region/state_required" core data returns nothing!

Tags: magento-1.8, core-config-data

This is driving me crazy! The `general/region/state_required` data from system->configuration cannot be retrieved by `Mage::getStoreConfig()` function. In the database, this value is presented, and data persistence works OK as well, i.e. changing the value in the CMS will take the change the database. The following is a abstraction from `system.xml` of Magento default Directory module.

```
<general>
        <groups>
            <country>
                <fields>
                    <optional_zip_countries translate="label">
                        <label>Postal Code is Optional for the following countries</label>
                        <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                    </optional_zip_countries>
                </fields>
            </country>
            <region translate="label">
                <label>States Options</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                    <state_required translate="label">
                        <label>State is required for</label>
                        <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    </state_required>
                    <display_all translate="label">
                        <label>Display not required State</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <sort_order>8</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    </display_all>
                </fields>
            </region>
        </groups>
    </general>
```

In fact, `general/region/display_all` returns null as well while it has a non-empty value. This is really weird, I have no idea about it now, can anyone please help?!

**--Update--**

Is it possible that this value is being overridden somewhere? Like some code hardcode this value to be null, it overrides the value in the db.

I tried a couple of methods suggested below, unfortunately they don't solve the problem here. Any more input from people?

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: You say 'changing the value in the cms' - can we assume you are talking about editing settings under `system -> config` and not cms pages?

Comment: @Marius Yes I did, I even tried rm -rf var/cache/*

Comment: @JonathanHussey Yes, I mean in the admin, under system > configuration, the point is that the value is getting persisted to the database.

Comment: Make sure you don't have different values for your config settings at website or store view level. Change the config scope from the top left dropdown.

Comment: @Marius, actually you don't see "States Options" except for in default config because <show_in_website> and <show_in_store> is 0 in system.xml, plus, I don't think it matters although I tried, but default is being used if neither of the other two has value.

Comment: Then check the db. Maybe something inserted some values in the `core_config_data` for the path `general/region/state_required` where the `scope` column is something else besides `default`. This means that those values are used for a website or store view, but shouldn't be there because like you said `show_in_website` and `show_in_store` are 0.

Comment: @Marius I checked, there's nothing wrong in the core_config_data for that path. That's why I feel weird about it.

Comment: Hey @Michael, did you ever find out why this was happening? I'm getting the same issue. I've grepped my source for both `display_all` and `XML_PATH_DISPLAY_ALL_STATES` - both rightfully only appear under `app/code/core`.

Comment: I'm a little late to the party, but it's 2016 I came across this exact issue and managed to figure it out. See my post below with the exact solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an article series by Alan Storm that covers the internals of **`Mage::getStoreConfig()`** extensively:

1. http://alanstorm.com/magento_config_tutorial
2. http://alanstorm.com/magento_config_declared_modules_tutorial
3. http://alanstorm.com/magento_loading_config_variables

In short, the value can come from:

1. `default`, `config/websites` and `config/stores` nodes in any XML file in `app/etc` (might even be in app/etc/modules, but it's highly unlikely)
2. `default`, `config/websites` and `config/stores` nodes in any module's `config.xml`
3. `core_config_data` table
4. `default`, `config/websites` and `config/stores` nodes in `app/etc/local.xml`

Configuration is loaded in this order, overriding existing values in each step (i.e. local.xml has highest priority)

It is also possible to set configuration values at runtime in the Config model without having them saved anywhere. Searching for **`Mage::getConfig()`** in your local code pool might help you finding it.

Comment: Yeah I did check out that series of tutorials, but they are helpful to me. I searched Mage::getConfig() and didn't find anywhere that these values are being overridden.

Comment: Did you search in all XML files? If everything fails, I would start debugging the code where the configuration gets loaded.

Comment: fschmengler, yeah I searched in all XML files, I think it's core functionality that shouldn't have any faults in it, unless plugins override it, but I didn't really find anything conflicting in the plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I've came across this exact issue and have figured out how to solve it.

When core config data is loaded from the database inside `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Config.php` on line 90

```
    // load all configuration records from database, which are not inherited
    $select = $read->select()
        ->from($this->getMainTable(), array('scope', 'scope_id', 'path', 'value'));
    if (!is_null($condition)) {
        $select->where($condition);
    }
    $rowset = $read->fetchAll($select);


    // set default config values from database
    foreach ($rowset as $r) {
        if ($r['scope'] !== 'default') {
            continue;
        }
        $value = str_replace($substFrom, $substTo, $r['value']);
        $xmlConfig->setNode('default/' . $r['path'], $value);
    }
```

all data is fetched from `core_config_data` and is saved in the xml structure. The data is loaded in same order as the `config_id`, so what happened was, there was an empty default value set and somewhere toward end of the table like this: [image]

notice id 2203. The path is set to `general` and the value is `NULL`!

When Magento processes id 2203 inside `lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php` on line 548:

```
public function setNode($path, $value, $overwrite=true)
{
    $xml = $this->_xml->setNode($path, $value, $overwrite);
    return $this;
}
```

The `NULL` default path value wipes the values inside its xml object.

How did this happen?

Well, if we look deeper inside Magento and check how the `core_config_data` table was created we see that

```
CREATE TABLE `{$installer->getTable('core_config_data')}` (
  `config_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `scope` enum('default','websites','stores','config') NOT NULL default 'default',
  `scope_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `path` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'general',
  `value` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`config_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `config_scope` (`scope`,`scope_id`,`path`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

so by default Magento sets the default path to `default`, default scope_id to `0`, but notice the `value` is *not supposed to be NULL*. So how did Magento save a `NULL` value?

Simple, someone/something did something like this `Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('general');` Try it and see for yourself; it'll work and Magento will save a `NULL` value in the table. If you're interested in understanding why it works, take a look inside `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php` line 1535:

```
public function saveConfig($path, $value, $scope = 'default', $scopeId = 0)
{
    $resource = $this->getResourceModel();
    $resource->saveConfig(rtrim($path, '/'), $value, $scope, $scopeId);

    return $this;
}
```

and inside `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Config.php` on line 184:

```
    public function saveConfig($path, $value, $scope, $scopeId)
{
    $writeAdapter = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
    $select = $writeAdapter->select()
        ->from($this->getMainTable())
        ->where('path = ?', $path)
        ->where('scope = ?', $scope)
        ->where('scope_id = ?', $scopeId);
    $row = $writeAdapter->fetchRow($select);

    $newData = array(
        'scope'     => $scope,
        'scope_id'  => $scopeId,
        'path'      => $path,
        'value'     => $value
    );

    if ($row) {
        $whereCondition = array($this->getIdFieldName() . '=?' => $row[$this->getIdFieldName()]);
        $writeAdapter->update($this->getMainTable(), $newData, $whereCondition);
    } else {
        $writeAdapter->insert($this->getMainTable(), $newData);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908309/mysql-column-set-to-not-null-but-still-allowing-null-values

*TL;DR; Solution*
Run this sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM magento.core_config_data WHERE value IS NULL;
```

and delete the row where `path` === `default` and `value IS NULL`(see my screenshot for reference).

`DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE scope = 'default' AND scope_id = 0 AND path = 'general' AND value IS NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

You can query the config after explicitly setting the store using either of the following:

> $config = Mage::getStoreConfig('inchoo/inchoo_group/inchoo_input', Mage::app()->getStore());

or

> Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0);
>
> $config = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/region/state_required');

You could also explicitly reload the configuration and then load the values using

> Mage::app()->getConfig()->reinit();
>
> Mage::getStoreConfig('inchoo/inchoo_group/inchoo_input', Mage::app()->getStore());

Comment: Not working unfortunately.

Comment: @Michael, see my solution.